# Incorporate oreo bits in cookie recipe

Tags: baking, cookies

What's the best way to incorporate prepacked oreo bits into a tested chocolate chip cookie recipe?

Mix with dry ingredients or wet ingredients?

Consider weight of oreo bits equivalent to flour, or equivalent to chocolate chips?

Am I mistaking my oreo fantasy and should just incorporate some sweetened cream cheese instead?

Or are oreo bits never meant to bake with cookies, at all? Right now, I substituted 50% of my weight in chocolate chips to oreo bits. The result: not as delectable as I imagined. It's getting done a bit faster than my normal recipe as well.

I know this is a long post -- thank you.

Comment: Are you including the cream filling, or just bits of cookies?

Comment: It's premade/premanufactured as bits. There's some cream throughout the mixture, but not as much, proportionally. So yes, there's little Oreo cream.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the best way to incorporate any bits into cookie dough is to first mix the dough completely and then mix in the bits - whether it be chocolate chips, nuts, oreo bits etc. This way the bits are not smashed and stay as undisturbed as possible and retain their shape as a whole.

So mix the dry and wet ingredients together to form the dough, then lightly mix in bits by hand (literally use your hands. I find it's the most gentle way) or with the paddle attachment on the lowest setting in a standing mixer.

As for the substituting... Go by volume (Catja's suggestion). I wouldn't sub more than half the chocolate chips with oreo bits, simply because it will make the end result too sweet (because of the oreo filling) and not chocolatey enough. Maybe use dark/bitter chocolate chips as well that aren't as sweet so that you are compensating for the sweetness of the oreo cream filling.

Comment: Oreos are likely less dense than chocolate chips... Why would you go by weight? In that case it would certainly be preferable to go by volume.